# Cakephp: name of the button is not included in post when using javascript

Tags: javascript, php, post, cakephp

I have a form with multiple submit buttons:

```
<?php if($is_admin){    
                        echo $this->Form->submit(__('Direct Assign'), ['id' => 'DAbtn', 'name' => 'btn', 'class' => 'button']);
                        echo $this->Form->button(__('Direct Assign & New Task From Copy'), ['id' => 'DANTbtn', 'name' => 'btn', 'class' => 'button']);} ?>
                    <?= $this->Form->button(__('Save as pending'), ['id' => 'SPbtn', 'name' => 'btn', 'class' => 'button']) ?>
                    <?= $this->Form->button(__('Save as pending & New Task From Copy'), ['id' => 'SPNTbtn', 'name' => 'btn', 'class' => 'button']) ?>
                    <?= $this->Form->end() ?>
```

So in the controller I can check which button has been clicked by:

```
$this->request->getData('btn')
```

But after I added some `javascript` for these buttons it stopped including `'btn'` in the Post vars.

```
//Don't allow multiple submit, disable submit button after submission of the form
    $( function() {
        $("#newTaskForm").submit( function() { 
            $(".button").attr("disabled", true);
            return true;

        });
    });
```

So I had to remove js code . Is it possible to fix that?

Comment: Disabled elements are not passed to the server. You will have to change the js to only disable the "other" buttons.

Comment: @DinoCoderSaurus But I want the form to be submitted the first time and then disable all the buttons in order not to allow the user to click same button multiple times

Comment: What do you know and when do you know it? If the flow is something like this: _Form: all buttons enabled -> click 1 button -> controller -> does some logic -> Form: no buttons enabled_  then the controller "knows" if some action has been taken. It needs to "share" that fact with the form.

Answer (score 3):

That is how HTML works, values of disabled elements are not being sent. 
    If you want to prevent multiple submit then use a read-only property instead of disabled.

```
$(function() {
    $("#newTaskForm").submit( function() { 
        $(".button").attr("readonly", true);
        return true;
    });
});
```

OR put any loader to avoid multiple send